# When methods have the name ...Async the exception "System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values" occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new Web API project
- Create a UsersController with the following code

.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = nameof(GetUserByIdAsync))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetUserByIdAsync([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        object user = null;

        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<object>> CreateUserAsync()
    {
        object user = null;

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUserByIdAsync), new { id = 1 }, user);
    }
}
```

- Call the url POST https://localhost:5001/users
- You will get the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied
>   values.

- Rename both methods by removing the `Async` from the method names, the methods should look like

  ```
  [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = nameof(GetUserById))]
  public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetUserById([FromRoute] int id)
  {
      // ...
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult<object>> CreateUser()
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Call the url POST https://localhost:5001/users again
- You will receive an empty 201 response

So I'm assuming the error occurs with the method names, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

To fix above error, you can try to set `SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames` option to `false`, like below.

```
services.AddControllers(opt => { 
    opt.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false; 
});
```

Or apply the `[ActionName]` attribute to preserve the original name.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = nameof(GetUserByIdAsync))]
[ActionName("GetUserByIdAsync")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetUserByIdAsync([FromRoute] int id)
{
```

Comment: I would rather go for this `opt.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false; ` but what is the reason? And what are the disadvantages?

Comment: It would be nice if you knew something about loss of features when setting the global bool

Comment: You can check this doc to know more about this change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#mvc-async-suffix-trimmed-from-controller-action-names