# Cannot resolve action in CreatedAtAction(nameof(ActionName))

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Api Controller and when create new object in database in Post method i want go to the other api action. But in case when method is specify called (GetByIdAsync) i got error `Cannot resolve action GetByIdAsync`. If action is called other name - everythink is ok.

Error code (additional screenshot [First screenshot](https://zapodaj.net/5ea455c763b5f.jpg.html))

```
[ApiController]
[Route("items")]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly ItemsRepository itemsRepository = new();

  [HttpGet("{id}")]
  public async Task<ActionResult<ItemDtos>> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
  {
    var item = (await itemsRepository.GetAsync(id)).AsDto();

    if (item == null)
    {
      return NotFound();
    }

    return item;
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(CreateItemDtos createItemDto)
  {
    var item = new Item {
    Name = createItemDto.Name, 
    Description = createItemDto.Description, 
    Price = createItemDto.Price,
    CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    };

    await itemsRepository.CreateAsync(item);

    //Cannot resolve action 'GetByIdAsync'
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetByIdAsync), new {id = item.Id}, item);
  }
}
```

Working Code (additional screenshot [Second screenshot](https://zapodaj.net/images/9a6115805bf6b.jpg))

```
[ApiController]
[Route("items")]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly ItemsRepository itemsRepository = new();

  [HttpGet("{id}")]
  public async Task<ActionResult<ItemDtos>> GetByIdAsync2(Guid id)
  {
    var item = (await itemsRepository.GetAsync(id)).AsDto();

    if (item == null)
    {
      return NotFound();
    }

    return item;
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(CreateItemDtos createItemDto)
  {
    var item = new Item {
    Name = createItemDto.Name, 
    Description = createItemDto.Description, 
    Price = createItemDto.Price,
    CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    };

    await itemsRepository.CreateAsync(item);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetByIdAsync2), new {id = item.Id}, item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When methods have the name ...Async the exception "System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values" occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202488/when-methods-have-the-name-async-the-exception-system-invalidoperationexcept)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why it gives this error but a solution is to assign it to a local variable and use that.

```cs
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(CreateItemDtos createItemDto)
  {
    var item = new Item
    {
        Name = createItemDto.Name, 
        Description = createItemDto.Description, 
        Price = createItemDto.Price,
        CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    };

    await itemsRepository.CreateAsync(item);

    var actionName = nameof(GetByIdAsync2);
    return CreatedAtAction(actionName, new { id = item.Id }, item);
  }
```

Comment: The really weird thing is if you change it to `const var actionName = nameof(GetByIdAsync2);` (i.e. make it a constant string) then R# gives the original error.

Comment: Have you tried adding options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false; See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63834605/4787999

Comment: Or use CreateAtRoute?

Comment: And name your method [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "CreateAsync")]

Answer (score 0):

only go to startup.cs or program.cs in .net 8 and add this code :

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false;
} );
```

this resolved my problem that was same your question